# navigation drawer with pinned (sticky) headers

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, pinned-header-list-view

I have a program showing sticky headers in a ListView. I want to apply this to the navigation drawer. Below is the code for PinnedSectionListActivity.java. How to input this ListView in the Navigation Drawer menu?

```js
import com.hb.examples.pinnedsection.R;

public class PinnedSectionListActivity extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

    static class SimpleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> implements com.hb.examples.PinnedSectionListView.PinnedSectionListAdapter {

        private static final int[] COLORS = new int[] {
            R.color.green_light, R.color.orange_light,
            R.color.blue_light, R.color.red_light };

        public SimpleAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
            generateDataset('A', 'Z', false);
        }

        public void generateDataset(char from, char to, boolean clear) {
         
         if (clear) clear();
         
            final int sectionsNumber = to - from + 1;
            prepareSections(sectionsNumber);

            int sectionPosition = 0, listPosition = 0;
            for (char i=0; i<sectionsNumber; i++) {
                Item section = new Item(Item.SECTION, String.valueOf((char)('A' + i)));
                section.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                section.listPosition = listPosition++;
                onSectionAdded(section, sectionPosition);
                add(section);

                final int itemsNumber = (int) Math.abs((Math.cos(2f*Math.PI/3f * sectionsNumber / (i+1f)) * 25f));
                for (int j=0;j<itemsNumber;j++) {
                    Item item = new Item(Item.ITEM, section.text.toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH) + " - " + j);
                    item.sectionPosition = sectionPosition;
                    item.listPosition = listPosition++;
                    add(item);
                }

                sectionPosition++;
            }
        }
        
        protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) { }
        protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) { }

        @Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            TextView view = (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            view.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            view.setTag("" + position);
            Item item = getItem(position);
            if (item.type == Item.SECTION) {
                //view.setOnClickListener(PinnedSectionListActivity.this);
                view.setBackgroundColor(parent.getResources().getColor(COLORS[item.sectionPosition % COLORS.length]));
            }
            return view;
        }

        @Override public int getViewTypeCount() {
            return 2;
        }

        @Override public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return getItem(position).type;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isItemViewTypePinned(int viewType) {
            return viewType == Item.SECTION;
        }

    }

    static class FastScrollAdapter extends SimpleAdapter implements SectionIndexer {

        private Item[] sections;

        public FastScrollAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override protected void prepareSections(int sectionsNumber) {
            sections = new Item[sectionsNumber];
        }

        @Override protected void onSectionAdded(Item section, int sectionPosition) {
            sections[sectionPosition] = section;
        }

        @Override public Item[] getSections() {
            return sections;
        }

        @Override public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
            if (section >= sections.length) {
                section = sections.length - 1;
            }
            return sections[section].listPosition;
        }

        @Override public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
            if (position >= getCount()) {
                position = getCount() - 1;
            }
            return getItem(position).sectionPosition;
        }

    }

 static class Item {

  public static final int ITEM = 0;
  public static final int SECTION = 1;

  public final int type;
  public final String text;

  public int sectionPosition;
  public int listPosition;

  public Item(int type, String text) {
      this.type = type;
      this.text = text;
  }

  @Override public String toString() {
   return text;
  }

 }

 private boolean hasHeaderAndFooter;
 private boolean isFastScroll;
 private boolean addPadding;
 private boolean isShadowVisible = true;
 private int mDatasetUpdateCount;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  if (savedInstanceState != null) {
      isFastScroll = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isFastScroll");
      addPadding = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("addPadding");
      isShadowVisible = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("isShadowVisible");
      hasHeaderAndFooter = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter");
  }
  initializeHeaderAndFooter();
  initializeAdapter();
  initializePadding();
 }

    @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putBoolean("isFastScroll", isFastScroll);
     outState.putBoolean("addPadding", addPadding);
     outState.putBoolean("isShadowVisible", isShadowVisible);
     outState.putBoolean("hasHeaderAndFooter", hasHeaderAndFooter);
 }

 @Override
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
     Item item = (Item) getListView().getAdapter().getItem(position);
     if (item != null) {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position + ": " + item.text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  menu.getItem(0).setChecked(isFastScroll);
  menu.getItem(1).setChecked(addPadding);
  menu.getItem(2).setChecked(isShadowVisible);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case R.id.action_fastscroll:
             isFastScroll = !isFastScroll;
             item.setChecked(isFastScroll);
             initializeAdapter();
             break;
         case R.id.action_addpadding:
             addPadding = !addPadding;
             item.setChecked(addPadding);
             initializePadding();
             break;
         case R.id.action_showShadow:
             isShadowVisible = !isShadowVisible;
             item.setChecked(isShadowVisible);
             ((PinnedSectionListView)getListView()).setShadowVisible(isShadowVisible);
             break;
         case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
             hasHeaderAndFooter = !hasHeaderAndFooter;
             item.setChecked(hasHeaderAndFooter);
             initializeHeaderAndFooter();
             break;
         case R.id.action_updateDataset:
          updateDataset();
          break;
     }
     return true;
 }

 private void updateDataset() {
  mDatasetUpdateCount++;
  SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) getListAdapter();
  switch (mDatasetUpdateCount % 4) {
   case 0: adapter.generateDataset('A', 'B', true); break;
   case 1: adapter.generateDataset('C', 'M', true); break;
   case 2: adapter.generateDataset('P', 'Z', true); break;
   case 3: adapter.generateDataset('A', 'Z', true); break;
  }
  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
 
 private void initializePadding() {
     float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
     int padding = addPadding ? (int) (16 * density) : 0;
     getListView().setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
 }

    private void initializeHeaderAndFooter() {
        setListAdapter(null);
        if (hasHeaderAndFooter) {
            ListView list = getListView();

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            TextView header1 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            header1.setText("First header");
            list.addHeaderView(header1);

            TextView header2 = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            header2.setText("Second header");
            list.addHeaderView(header2);

            TextView footer = (TextView) inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, false);
            footer.setText("Single footer");
            list.addFooterView(footer);
        }
        initializeAdapter();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initializeAdapter() {
        getListView().setFastScrollEnabled(isFastScroll);
        if (isFastScroll) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                getListView().setFastScrollAlwaysVisible(true);
            }
            setListAdapter(new FastScrollAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
        } else {
            setListAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Item: " + v.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you add your listview inside your DrawerLayout. Follow this link for example : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Comment: add the code in navidrawer listview

Comment: I tried. There are following errors:

In MainActivity> mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
Error: The method setAdapter(ListAdapter) in the type ListView is not applicable for the arguments(PinnedSectionListActivity)

In PinnedSectionListActivity> 
case R.id.action_fastscroll:
case R.id.action_addpadding:
case R.id.action_showShadow:
case R.id.action_showHeaderAndFooter:
case R.id.action_updateDataset:

Error: cannot be resolved or is not a field

Here is my source code: http://www.filedropper.com/stickynav

Comment: I rectified the second error by adding the 4 id's in menu.xml in "res" folder. Now just the first error remains in MainActivity.java file.